# How is makepri.exe integrated into MSBuild?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime

I am trying to understand the [Resource Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj552947.aspx) in WinRT.

The documentation says:

> MakePRI.exe is a command line tool used for creating and dumping PRI files. It is integrated as part of MSBuild within Microsoft Visual Studio, but can be useful for developers to create packages by hand or by custom build systems.

I want to know how is makepri.exe integrated into MSBuild, how can I configure it?

Comment: Call me a pedant, but why are you calling it "make_pri.exe", when you even quote a MSDN reference with the correct name "makepri.exe"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your csproj file imports this file for C# XAML apps:

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v11.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.Targets
```

which in turn imports this that is common to Windows XAML apps written in any language:

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v11.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.Targets
```

finally it imports this file that includes the makepri configuration commands:

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppxPackage.Targets
```

In there there is something called "_GenerateProjectPriFileDependsOn" which is composed of these tasks:

```
        _GeneratePrisForPortableLibraries;
        _GetPriFilesFromPayload;
        _ComputeInputPriFiles;
        _GenerateProjectPriConfigurationFiles;
        _CalculateInputsForGenerateProjectPriFileCore;
        _GenerateProjectPriFileCore;
        _AddFileReadsAndFileWritesForProjectPri;
        _CreateProjectPriFileItem;
        _ExpandPriFiles;
```

Seems like it runs some tasks to list resources, generate a config file for makepri and then runs makepri.

The targets files are a bit cryptic to analyze and I would break here and look for these makepri config files. If you search under the obj folder of your app project you can find a file named priconfig.xml. In fact if you run makepri.exe you will find that there is a makepri command  for creating config files and if you try that (by running makepri.exe createconfig) - you will learn that priconfig.xml is a common name for the config file. If you run "makepri new" you will see what the options are for generating the pri file and the call syntax ("MakePri.exe new /pr  /cf  [options]"). Now the priconfig.xml file lists some other files like pri.resfiles which seems to list the pri files imported from referenced assemblies and layout.resfiles which is a list of all content files to package in the app.

So this is roughly how makepri is integrated into msbuild. Now Windows Dev Center has the whole topic on [Resource Management System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj552947.aspx) which describes how you would configure it if you wanted to run it manually.

There is also another related topic you might want to read on [naming resources using qualifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965324%28v=win.10%29.aspx) which shows how resources named with various qualifiers (scale, locale, etc.) or located in qualifier folders get picked up.